# Codeigniter send google mail error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, ssl

I use Codeignter in host Cpanel. On local i can send email by google account but on host Cpanel  it error.
This is my config:

```
$ci = get_instance();

$ci->load->library('email');

$config['protocol'] = "smtp";

$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";

$config['smtp_port'] = 465;

$config['smtp_user'] = "xxx@gmail.com"; 

$config['smtp_pass'] = "xxx";

$config['charset'] = "utf-8";

$config['mailtype'] = "html";
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";

$ci->email->initialize($config);
```

Openssl enabled on host.

This is the error alert:

```
.....
Message:  fsockopen() ...: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 
.....
```

Please help me!
Sorry my english is bad

Answer (score 1):

**#1** Make sure you have **ssl_module** in Apache and **allow_url_fopen** in php.ini Open or enabled.

**#2** Make sure you have POP3 enabled in gmail Settings

**#3** if you are working within proxy or firewall enabled network; make sure you have desired PORT (465) open.

Try this self TESTED Code.

```
$config['useragent']    = 'CodeIgniter';
$config['protocol']     = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host']    = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_user']    = '*****developer@gmail.com'; // Your gmail id
$config['smtp_pass']    = '**********'; // Your gmail Password
$config['smtp_port']    = 465;
$config['wordwrap']     = TRUE;    
$config['wrapchars']    = 76;
$config['mailtype']     = 'html';
$config['charset']      = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['validate']     = FALSE;
$config['priority']     = 3;
$config['newline']      = "\r\n";
$config['crlf']         = "\r\n";

$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('trimantradeveloper@gmail.com', 'TSS DEV');
$this->email->to('trimantra@trimantra.com'); 
$this->email->cc('trimantra@gmail.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.');    

$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = Array(
'protocol' => 'smtp',
'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
'smtp_port' => 465,
'smtp_user' => 'xxx',
'smtp_pass' => 'xxx',
'mailtype'  => 'html', 
'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
$this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

// Set to, from, message, etc.

$result = $this->email->send();
```

Comment: Thank for help! I will try this way but it also not working for me. I searched very much in google but have not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server's apache has enabled for the ssl module.Most probably it can be the reason.Or you can do other way around.Check removing the google's smtp ssl method.If you do that you want to change the smtp port form 465 to 587